# Changing model prior to adding to database in .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to create an updateable events page for a website. An event may or may not have an image.

In the model, I have simply used a bool called HasImage - if this is true, then the display page will display an image called [EventID].jpg

I figured this would be the simplest way of doing it. I have added the code to upload the image, and images are uploading correctly, but I can't work out how to use the existence of the image in the create form to set HasImage correctly.

This is a simplified version of the code...

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Date,Details,HasImage")] Events events, IFormFile file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string hasImage = file.Length > 0 ? "False" : "True";
            ModelState.SetModelValue("events.HasImage",  new ValueProviderResult(hasImage, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            // also tried but failed: events.HasImage=hasImage (where hasImage was a bool)
            _context.Add(events);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            int NewID = cH_Events.ID;
            var fileName = NewID + ".jpg";
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                [upload stuff here]
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(Events);
    }
```

NB HasImage does not appear on the form. It doesn't work whether or not I include it in the Bind list. I am assuming this is the best way to do this. An alternative would be to create a hidden form variable and use JavaScript.

Comment: What does your code to show the Events view look like?
Does the events get stored in the DB with the file uploaded?

If so you can check if the image exists on the GET method of the page used to view the Events.
Then set the hasImage on the ViewModel.

Comment: The code in the view page works fine if I manually change the hasImage value. I could check that the image itself exists instead, but wouldn't that use more server resources?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a tortuous process of trial and error, I have found a solution.

Instead of trying to change the model before adding to the database, I've found that it's possible to add to database as normal, *then* change the model, and then update changes.

This is a sample of the code that works (I have also changed hasImage to ImageType so that I can use different file types)

```
              _context.Add(Events);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            int NewID = Events.ID;

            if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                [upload image code]

                cH_Events.ImageType = fileType;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```